# Comunicar com Arduíno pela porta COM4

Tags: c#, arduino, porta-serial

Criei um código em c# para me comunicar com o Arduíno uno.  Ele tem que me passar qual a tag passou pelo leitor rfid e mostre em uma textbox o valor.

Adicionei a serialport1.

Código:

```
        serialPort1.Open();
        string entrada = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        serialPort1.Close();
        txtIDTag.Text = entrada;
```

Erro quando executo:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: A porta 'COM4' não existe.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem certeza que o Arduino está conectado na porta COM4?

Comment: tenho certeza sim

Comment: Executou o programa como administrador? Pode ser falta de permissão, aparentemente.

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar Anderson, Encontrei o problema. A porta estava sendo usada por outra aplicação.